# How to make Resharper gutter icons larger

Tags: resharper

Is there any way to increase the size of Resharper gutter icons?

E.g. I want the gutter icons displayed against a TestMethod to be larger (to make them easier to hit with a mouse click)

Comment: I know it's not what you're asking, but you can also run tests with keyboard shortcuts, or by hitting <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Enter</kbd> on the method or class name.

Comment: Yup @citizenmatt, I think this is a case of tunnel vision in terms of wanting to use my Resharper licence or if not then it is just too much of a reach to the keyboard....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess you are either using a small screen or running at a super high resolution. I don't expect there is a way to alter the size of the Resharper icons. Some solutions to your problem could be:

- Run at a lower resolution
- Use a bigger screen
- Get stronger glasses
- Use a more accurate mouse
- Practice your clicking skills by playing lots of FPS games
- Learn the keyboard shortcuts
- Don't drink whilst testing :)

Comment: Thanks Piers, I tried the stronger glasses strategy and came to the conclusion that the root cause is an non-deterministic (imprecise) right-hand movement. I'll try a Practice strategy combined with a "SlowDownAndBePatient" strategy